# How to force relative that to be absolute in linux?

Tags: shell

I have a third-part software with external configuration that takes "path to file" as input parameter. Unfortunately, this software concatenates path given with some predefined path. For example, it expects 'data/images' as parameter and will use '/Users/someuser/work/source/data/images'. I want to specify and absolute path, but giving something like '/tmp/images' to this software will just result in unexisting path '/Users/someuser/work/source//tmp/images' being used :(. Is it some path trick i can use alongside of '..' so i can give software `something` that will result in absolute path after software concatenates it with predefined one. Using '..' works but it's not a very good solution since path configuration is static and predefined path software use can change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are myriads of possibilities to make `/Users/someuser/work/source/XXX` to point wherever you want to in Linux:

- Use symlinks - doing something like:

  ```
  ln -s /wherever/you/want /Users/someuser/work/source/XXX
  ```

  would make `/Users/someuser/work/source/XXX` to appear as a directory. If some software would travel there and/or write files there, they would end up in `/wherever/you/want`.
- Mount some other filesystem in `XXX`, i.e.

  ```
  mount /dev/something /Users/someuser/work/source/XXX
  ```

  This way you'll get your /dev/something device mounted right at the directory the application would write to.
- Do a "bind mount", i.e. rebind a part of some other filesystem (already mounted) to `XXX`:

  ```
  mount -o bind /wherever/you/want /Users/someuser/work/source/XXX
  ```

  It works much like a symlink, but it's much harder to detect by application. Application might easily check whether target directory is a symlink and refuse writing there, while bind mount method provides a normal directory, but it's contents would
- Use a unionfs-like filesystem, such as [unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) or [aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) - this way you can "unify", i.e. mount simultaneously several filesystems in one directory (i.e. `XXX`)
- Play some tricks with LD_PRELOAD and libraries that override methods, such as `open()`, `fopen()`, etc - the most prominent one is [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), namely, you might want to check out [Union-like filesystems for FUSE](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=UnionFileSystems).

Answer (score 0):

If you symlink `/Users/someuser/work/source/` to `/` (root)

```
work$ ln -s / source
```

Every path there will be based off the root:

```
/Users/someuser/work/source/tmp/images
```

will point to

```
/tmp/images
```

which you can check by

```
work$ ls source/tmp/images
```

Comment: Maybe call it something like `rootdir` rather than `source`.

Comment: As i previously noted, the path software use as root is dynamic, so symlinking it will be hard.

Comment: As you may read from my answer, if we symlink **to the FS root**, nothing is ever hard. Please read my answer once again. `mount --bind` based solutions are not as near as flexible as mine.